# How to import and use minified local script in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zebra-printers

I am trying to import Browserprint script that i have downloaded locally inside src/resources

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/extensions 
import "../Resources/BrowserPrint-Zebra-1.1.250.min.js"; 
//eslint-disable-next-line import/extensions 
import "../Resources/BrowserPrint-3.1.250.min.js";
```

Then i am just trying to do a simple console log to check if the library is there

```
useEffect(() => {
  getData();
  console.log(window.BrowserPrint);
  // setupPrinter();
}, []);
```

I get undefined. I also tried waiting a few seconds before running the console.log() but its still undefined
Visual studio code seems to catch the library as it give me autofill suggestions. So filename and path is 100% correct.
I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Someone who has used this library in their project or any other?

Comment: If this is for Zebra Printers [wouldn't this be easier to use with React](https://github.com/lhilario/zebra-browser-print-wrapper)? If it is the Zebra library BrowserPrinter JS file is apparently proprietary (not open-source) so we can't check it.

Comment: I saw this library. But it appears dead. So i am trying to do this without it.